# Site Use Confirmation and Deletion - Custom Email - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, delete, sharepoint-email, site-usage

Is it possible to send a custom email while using the "site use Confirmation and Deletion" from central administration in SharePoint 2013.

I would like to send a customized email with the links included in the email, Is there a way possible to do this?